# What does the "default" generic constraint do?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-9.0

The following code compiles, but it seems that Microsoft's docs don't mention this particular constraint type at all.

```
class TestGenericsBase<T1>
{
    public virtual void Method1<T>(T arg)
    {
    }
}

class TestGenerics : TestGenericsBase<object>
{
    public override void Method1<T>(T arg)
        where T : default // what does this do?
    {
    }
}
```

Any idea what does it do? The only clue I have so far is that it only works on methods.

Comment: Note that `where T : default` is closely related to `where T : default(T)` and `var something = default(T)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [`default`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-9.0/nullable-reference-types-specification.md#default-constraint) constraint can be found in C#9 design proposal for nullable reference types. It was added to disambiguate between `class` in `struct` constraints in overriden or explicitly implemented methods for nullable generic parameters  `T?`.

More details also can be found in the [Unconstrained type parameter annotations proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-9.0/unconstrained-type-parameter-annotations.md#default-constraint)

> To allow annotations for type parameters that are not constrained to
> reference types or value types, C#9 allows a new `where T : default`
> constraint.

These constraints and annotations are working within [nullable contexts](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-9.0/nullable-reference-types-specification.md#nullable-contexts)

Comment: Interesting, that Microsoft calls it "C#9" (without a blank before the number). Looks wrong/strange to me.

Comment: @UweKeim Just the one who wrote the proposal; "C#8" is also mentioned there.

Comment: I wonder if there is any up-to-date description of all available new features, rather than a proposal?

Comment: @user626528 I don't think that there is more up-to-date description of C# features rather then [csharplang](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) and [roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) repositories. ECMA standard exists only for C#5 and draft version for C#6, all versions after then will come as proposals, as you can read on [C# reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/)